# XtraGrid: How to get RowIndicator Column?

Tags: .net, vb.net, devexpress, xtragrid

In **XtraGrid**, there is a column which shows *RowIndicators*. How to get that column?

I want to change column header as highlighted in picture at top left corner.

[image]

Note that I am able to customize the RowIndicator icons using `CustomDrawRowIndicator` event. But now I need to customize its header.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's correct to use the `CustomDrawRowIndicator` event for this task. To determine that it's raised for the header, use the `e.Info.Kind` property:

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawRowIndicator(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowIndicatorCustomDrawEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Info.Kind == DevExpress.Utils.Drawing.IndicatorKind.Header) {
        // my code
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```